# How to List Custom Post Type Titles Based on Theirs Taxonomy Terms Inside a Nested Loop

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries, multi-taxonomy-query

I am trying to list at least the last three updated Custom Post Type's title lets call it "Cast" inside another loop which is listed based on the Taxonomy terms called "Actress" I used the following loop to get the list of my tax terms:

```
$taxonomy = 'actress';
$term_args=array(
  'hide_empty' => false,
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC'
);
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$term_args);
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
echo '<li>' . $tax_term->name.'</li>';
}
?>
</ul>
<?php
```

well this helped me to list the terms but I am really confused how to add the list of each terms associated custom post? to be more clear I illustrate following image,hopefully this will give you an idea what I am seeking for? Can you please help me to figure out how to do this? Thanks

**Update**

```
<?php

get_header();
//list terms in a given taxonomy
$taxonomy = 'actress';
$term_args=array(
  'hide_empty' => false,
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC'
);
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$term_args);
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
$loop = new WP_Query(
                  array(
                    'post_type' => 'cast',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'actress',
                            'field'=>'id', 
                            'terms' => $tax_term->ID
                           )
                    ),
                    'posts_per_page' => 3
                  )
             );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        $loop->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }

}

?>
</ul>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieval of multiple posts in WordPress is almost always handled by [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class (or `get_posts()` function that wraps it).

There is quite *a lot* of documentation and information to it, but to narrowing it down to your specific case you will need to:

- set up posts loop for each term
- pass as arguments to each loop:

  - your post type
  - desired number of posts
  - current term you wish to fetch posts for (see "taxonomy parameters" section in docs)

Comment: Hi Rarst, Thanks for your complete hints but to be honest I a little bit( let's say a lot :-) confused here! I almost know hoe to get Custom Post Types based on one taxonomy term (please take a look at update code above) but I am not sure how to integrate this post with listed terms!

Comment: @MonaCoder you pretty much have it nailed, you just need to pass term information from your loop with terms to querying posts, something like `'field'=>'id', 'terms' => $tax_term->ID` in taxonomy query.

Comment: @ Rarst, I tried this a lot and ended up with above, again, updated code. Still not working, I mean I am only getting the list of terms and not Post Titles under each term! Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @MonaCoder move `WP_Query` inside your `foreach` loop (since you want to run it for every term) and see [very first example of usage in docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage) for how to output titles using it.

Comment: OMG! this is gonna kill me!, I updated the code as above, No Errors! but I am not getting any of the lists! Not Terms neither CPTs

Comment: @MonaCoder hmm, try `$tax_term->term_id`, I might have remembered it wrong typing off the top of my head

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11522/discussion-between-mona-coder-and-rarst)